# REACT warning when trying to render table

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-framework, react

I am new to REACT and I am trying to render my SharePoint list data in a table onto a SharePoint page.

I am able to render successfully but then I get the following warning in the console.

**react-dom.development.js:82 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of .
    in tr (created by Table)
    in Table (created by App)
    in App**

I then change the render portion to this

```
    render() {
        var { tblData } = this.state;
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                return (

            tblData.map(function (data) {
                return (

                            <Table
                    title={data.Title}
                    fname={data.FirstName}
                    lname={data.LastName}
                    phone={data.Phone}
                    age={data.age}
                />
                )
            })
        )


        </tbody>
        </table>
    }
```

I then get the following error

````
  47 | 
  48 |             tblData.map(function (data) {
> 49 |                 return (
     |                 ^
  50 | 
  51 |                             <Table
  52 |                     title={data.Title}```

what am I doing wrong?  Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

Seems the warning because of you're render table inside tbody(not tr>td).

You may use jQuery datatable which is used common.

My demo:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './ReactDataTable.module.scss';
import { IReactDataTableProps } from './IReactDataTableProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'datatables.net';

export interface IListItem{ 
  Id:number,
  Title:string,
  Description:string
}

export default class ReactDataTable extends React.Component<IReactDataTableProps, {}> {

  private async _getListData(): Promise<IListItem[]> {
    let items2 : Array<IListItem> = new Array<IListItem>();
    await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("TestList").items.select("Id", "Title","Description","Created").get().then((items: any[]) => {
      //console.log(items);
      items.forEach(item => {
        var typeItem:IListItem={Id:item.Id,Title:item.Title,Description:item.Description}
        items2.push(typeItem);
      }); 
    });
    this.setState({ listItems: items2 });
    return items2;    
  }
  public componentDidMount(){
    this._getListData().then(items=>{
      console.log(items);
    });
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.getAll().then(values=> {
    var jsonArray =values.map(function (i) {
    return [
    i.Id,
    i.Title,
    i.IsDisplay,
    i.Created
    ];
    });

    var table =$(this.refs.table).DataTable({
    data: jsonArray,
    columns: [
    { title: "ID" },
    { title: "Title" },
    { title: "IsDisplay" },
    { title: "Created" },
    ]
    });
    });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactDataTableProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.reactDataTable }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <table
              ref='table'
              className={ styles.dataTable }>
              </table>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Another guideline thread](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/display-sharepoint-list-data-with-jquery-datatable-in-sharepoint-frameworkspfx/)